# How to see the mismatched Proposal Responses?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm using [the test network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/test-network).

I found once I perform certain operations and run the following command, Hyperledger throws error

> $ peer chaincode invoke -C mychannel -n basic -c '{"function":"openCashDesk","Args":["1"]}'
>
> Error: could not assemble transaction: ProposalResponsePayloads do not match - proposal response: version:1 response:<status:200 payload:"true" > payload:"\n \036\035\323\257\2240fiW=\217*~\253t\226\222\252Qr1\376\227P\362\354E\207\266\022\202\333\022\305\002\n\250\002\0227\n\n_lifecycle\022)\n'\n!namespaces/fields/cocome/Sequence\022\002\010\005\022\354\001\n\006cocome\022\341\001\n(\n"CoCoMESystemImpl.currentCashDeskPK\022\002\010\t\n\006\n\004Sale\032\254\001\n\004Sale\032\243\001[{"amount":0.0,"assoicatedPayment":null,"BelongedCashDeskPK":1,"BelongedstorePK":null,"containedSalesLine":[],"isComplete":false,"isReadytoPay":false,"time":null}]\032\t\010\310\001\032\004true"\r\022\006cocome\032\0031.0" endorsement:<endorser:"\n\007Org1MSP\022\252\006-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\np4tHO0MbsKT/xPB5L2DVk0rsTcznpKAPUCZCh2Q=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" signature:"0E\002!\000\240\361\207\250\217a}\337\326Z\0376sfsu\261AQ9\026\215\r\322\305\024\312\356\351=\227\202\002 9|\224v$LDhiS3\007\320\262 ;\Ir@\363\253\343h\257I\376O\031\333\001\243" >

As https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/txflow.html says "The application ... compares the proposal responses to determine if the proposal responses are the same.", how do I see the mismatched Proposal Responses?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply log what you are returning from your chaincodes and inspect logs.

Typical errors in chaincodes that cause proposal response mismatch:

- Using random numbers or UUIDs.
- Using current timestamps (instead of the transaction timestamp, for instance).
- Returning objects serialized as a string in an undeterministic way. For instance, you convert a JSON object to a string before returning it. Peer 1 serializes element "a" before element "b", but peer 2 serializes "b" before "a".
- Consuming external services without some kind of oracle.
- Rely on the chaincode memory state instead of on the world state, as the first one may be different between peers if you are doing such kind of things.

In general, anything you can think of that causes different peers to return different responses for the same chaincode operation. Smart contracts must be deterministic.

Comment: What you said makes sense from a developer point of view. In case I'm a blockchain manager, I suspect some peers are behaving funny, how would I inspect their responses?

Comment: You have posted only a part of the error, but it will probably show you various versions of the response: "version: 1", "version: 2"... Compare those versions and look for differences.

Comment: I included the full error message but I don't see "version 2".

Comment: Mmm... OK. Then that may be the problem. You may have a endorsement policy that requires more than one endorsement, but you are only gathering one. With `--peerAddresses` you can specify multiple addresses to fulfill your endorsement policy: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerchaincode.html#peer-chaincode-invoke. If not specified another policy when instantiating the chaincode, you probably require endorsements from peers from N/2+1 organizations.

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/b4c273174f880b852ddee14e9f633f7d8ba4d559/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer/proposal_response.pb.go#L35 says the Version field means the protocol version. I don't think it means the first response, the second response. Have you ever seen Version 2?

Comment: Maybe. I usually perform transactions with other tools and my endorsements usually match, but I remember to see all responses when it eventually happened. Anyway, as I say, without `--peerAddresses`, you seem to be querying only one peer (the default one for your client). With only one response, it is impossible to mismatch itself, so the problem must be that the endorsement policy is not fulfilled. Use `--peerAddresses` to specify peers from different organizations.

Comment: Use of the peer command to invoke transactions only exists for test purposes so don't expect too much from it in regards how it works or what information it provides back. In reality you would develop a client application to submit or evaluate transactions. If you use the node-sdk 2.2 then it will report an error if the proposal responses don't match (it's a basic binary comparison) and that error object contains all the proposal responses and then you would have to work out where the differences occur in your client application code. Other SDKs may differ in behaviour around this.